# php taking long time to load data from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to load data from 10 devices (temp and pressure sensors) every minute into a webpage and reload the page every minute (These devices send data to DB every minute). but the problem is, sometimes PHP takes too long to run. I often get a PHP timeout error. Is it the problem with the code or what might be the reason for it? ( These devices are sending data with the help of the HTTP post method).

```
<?php

function getData($device_id)
{
    include 'test_db_info.php';
    $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);

    if ($conn->connect_error)
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT temperature, preassure, info_time FROM test where device_id = '$device_id'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $conn->close();
    return $result;
}


$deviceID=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

foreach ($deviceID as $id)
{
    $rows_data= getData($id);

    // if there is data, disyplay the data
    if (!empty($rows_data))
    {
      foreach ($rows_data as $row)
      {
        echo '<table class= "mainTableClass"; >';

        
        echo '<tr><th>Device</th>';                       // first row - device
        echo '<td >' . $id. '</td></tr>';

        echo '<tr><th>Temp</th>';                        // second row - temperature
        echo '<td >' . $row['temperature']. '</td></tr>';

        echo '<tr><th>Preassure</th>';                   //third row - Preassure
        echo '<td >' . $row['preassure']. '</td></tr>';

        echo '<tr><th>Time</th>';                        // fourth row - time
        echo '<td >' . $row['info_time']. '</td></tr>';

        echo "</table>";

      }
    }
}

?>
```

[image]

Comment: You should open a database connection and re-use the same connection, reconnecting is a relatively expensive process.

Comment: Try to get all device data in single query: `"SELECT temperature, preassure, info_time FROM test where device_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)"`

Comment: Nigel's suggest is valid although it shouldn't cause such a big lag, I'd search for other issues. Add some time measurements into your script to determine which part is most problematic. Increase execution time temporary to make that debugging easier.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid running query inside loop. I've changed the code in a better way. It will fetch the results in less than a second.

```
include 'test_db_info.php';
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);

if ($conn->connect_error)
{
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$deviceID=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

$devices_arr = implode("','",$deviceID);

$query = "SELECT device_id, temperature, preassure, info_time FROM test where device_id IN ('".$devices_arr."')";

$data=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$devices = array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){

    $devices[$row['device_id']] = $row;

}

foreach ($deviceID as $id){

    if(isset($devices[$id])){

        $row = $devices[$id];

        echo '<table class= "mainTableClass"; >';

        echo '<tr><th>Device</th>';                       // first row - device
        echo '<td >' . $id. '</td></tr>';

        echo '<tr><th>Temp</th>';                        // second row - temperature
        echo '<td >' . $row['temperature']. '</td></tr>';

        echo '<tr><th>Preassure</th>';                   //third row - Preassure
        echo '<td >' . $row['preassure']. '</td></tr>';

        echo '<tr><th>Time</th>';                        // fourth row - time
        echo '<td >' . $row['info_time']. '</td></tr>';

        echo "</table>";

    }
}
```